# grow div while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, height

I have 3 divs that are loading content inside dynamically (rendering response from ajax calls) and because of this the divs have different height.

**CSS**

```
div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>response from ajax 1</div>
<div>response from ajax 2</div>
<div>response from ajax 3</div>
```

I need to make all divs the same height of the tallest `div` but the ajax calls are executed at different times so I need to calculate the height many times (maybe looking if the scrollbar grow?). I was thinking about calculating the height of the entire document but it doesn´t work or I´m doing it incorrectly because is generating an infinite scroll.

**JS**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('div').css('height', $(document).height());
})
```

I read about the cool flexbox solution but I can´t apply that at this time so that´s why I need to calculate the height using JS. thanks so much smart people.

Comment: Wrap all the responses in another div and make it's height auto

Comment: you can make a function that calculates the highest div and returns that value, and then apply the value to the divs

Comment: @rourdefran I would love to see something like that.